# Need To Close A Panel When Clicked Outside (Lost Focus)

Tags: vb.net, focus, panel

I have an issue that I cannot seem to overcome.

In my application, I have a custom class that loads a form into a panel upon startup.  Then when I click a button on my main form I show the panel as visible revealing the form to the user.

My problem is that I want to be able to hide the panel when a user clicks outside of it (back onto the main form).

so far I have tried `Form_Deactivate`, `Form_Leave`, `Form_LostFocus`, `Panel_Leave` and `Panel_LostFocus` events but nothing will seem to trigger an event consistently to hide the panel.  The only thing that works is if the user clicks inside the form (on a listview control) once the form is visible and then clicks outside of the form.

Is there anyway I can ensure this event gets called everytime whether the user clicks the form or not?

So far my code looks something like:

```
Public Class cls_UserObjects

    Private frm As frmUsers
    Public pnl As Panel

    Public Sub ShowUserPanel()
        Try
            frm = New frmUsers
            frm.TopLevel = False
            pnl.Controls.Add(frm)
            frm.Show()
            frm.Focus()
....
End Class
```

Then in my main form I call the code below to build the form into the panel:

```
class_Users.pnl = pnlUsers
class_Users.ShowUserPanel()
```

And `pnlUsers.Visible = True` to show it to the user

I just can't seem to close it.  I understand that Panels don't support the LostFocus properly, however, I can't find away around this.  Maybe it has something to do with how I am opening my form/panel but I was advised to use classes to open forms so I can have more control over the controls within my forms from outside calls.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: This is most likely related to a form embedded in the panel; questions like this seem to come up in relation to this periodically.  *In this case* since frmUsers is more or less a glorified control, it could be created and added as such in the form containing the control.  Then you could try to hide the panel as a result of the frm.Deactivate event.

Answer (score 1):

MouseLeave event works, the panel hides immediately once it leaves the panel.

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
    Panel1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sabre, but I still have to click inside the form for it to register a MouseLeave event.  Also, it doesn't seem to be firing every time.